# How to count difference in consecutive timestamps in SQL?

Tags: sql, timestamp, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

So I have some data which looks like this:

```
   USER_ID      text_field                   TIMESTAMP 
1  0000001          dragon     2021-06-04 21:23:30.612      
2  0000001          dragon     2021-06-04 21:23:55.411
3  0000001          dragon     2021-06-04 21:27:35.418
4  0000002         pitbull     2021-06-04 19:17:53.211
5  0000002          dragon     2021-06-04 19:47:53.211
6  0000002          dragon     2021-06-04 19:57:53.211
7  0000003          dragon     2021-06-05 10:00:53.211
8  0000003          dragon     2021-06-05 10:02:53.211
9  0000003           earth     2021-06-05 10:04:53.211
10 0000003          dragon     2021-06-05 10:06:53.211
11 0000003          dragon     2021-06-05 10:08:53.211
```

Amd what I would like to see is **the difference between the first and last timestamp for a consquetive entries featuring the word `dragon`**

So In ID 0000001, We have all entries as `dragon` so for this case I want row 3 minus row 1. that is the max(timestamp) - min(timestamp) for all entries featuring dragon and ID = 0000001.

For ID 2, notice not all is dragon, but I want this same difference for just the `dragon` entries.

It's also possible that an ID can have non consquetive `dragon` entries, like in ID 0000003. Here I need **a difference for the consquetive entries in both chunks.** This means for ID 0000003, I need `row 8 - row 7` AND `row 11 - row 10`.

Final output:

```
USER_ID  time_diff
0000001       (2021-06-04 21:27:35.418  - 2021-06-04 21:23:30.612)
0000002       (2021-06-04 19:57:53.211  - 2021-06-04 19:47:53.211)
0000003       (2021-06-05 10:02:53.211  - 2021-06-05 10:00:53.211)
0000003       (2021-06-05 10:08:53.211  - 2021-06-05 10:06:53.211)
```

And obviously those are just the equations for time_diff, i really want the difference in this column.

Comment: what if row 7 did not exist? how would the time_diff be determined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you specifically care about "dragon"s only, you can identify each group using a cumulative sum of non-dragons up to each row.  Then aggregate:

```
select userid, min(timestamp), max(timestamp)
from (select t.*,
             sum(case when text_field <> 'dragon' then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by user_id order by timestamp) as grp
      from t
     ) t
where text_field = 'dragon'
group by userid, grp;
```

You can calculate the difference however you like.

Answer (score 1):

here is how you can do it :

```
select user_id , min(TIMESTAMP) , max(TIMESTAMP), datediff(second,max(TIMESTAMP),min(TIMESTAMP)) time_diff
from (
  select *
   , rank() over (partition by user_id order by TIMESTAMP)
    -rank() over (partition by user_id,text_field order by TIMESTAMP) rn
  from users
) t
where text_field = 'dragon'
group by user_id , rn 
order by user_id
```